# How does _dl_runtime_resolve achieve thread safety?

Tags: linker, elf, libc

I'm reading this article: https://ypl.coffee/dl-resolve/

Since the GOT table is resolved at runtime (at first call to this function), I'm wondering how does `_dl_runtime_resolve` ensure it's multi-thread safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does `_dl_runtime_resolve` ensure it's multi-thread safe?

Any *pure* function is thread-safe by definition.

`_dl_runtime_resolve` is not pure (updates the GOT slot), but if two threads are resolving the same symbol in parallel, both threads will resolve to the same symbol (i.e. they'll compute the exact same target address), and will write the same value into the GOT slot.

While *technically* this is a data race, *practically* it doesn't lead to any observable problems.